# Rename section and change order of sections in QGIS Reporter

Tags: qgis, atlas-generator

I am new to the qgis reporter and am wondering, if I can change the name of different sections and also change the order of the sections.

In my report, I will have approx. over 10 sections, and it would give me a much better overview if I can name the sections myself.

I searched on the web and watched a few tutorial videos, but am not able to find a solution. Any suggestion would be of great help.

[image]

Comment: These are obvious functionalities that the Report feature *should* have, but if they exist I can't find them. You've done your due diligence of searching for tutorials and references. I suggest waiting a few days and see if you get an answer here, and if not, make a [feature request](https://issues.qgis.org).